# Problems with bar chart in aChartengine

Tags: bar-chart, achartengine

I have some problems creating a bar chart.
This is my code:

```
GraphicalView mChart;
XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
XYSeries mCurrentSeries;
XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer;
mCurrentSeries = new XYSeries("Sample Data");
mDataset.addSeries(mCurrentSeries);
mCurrentRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mCurrentRenderer);
mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(1);
mRenderer.setXAxisMax(7);
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Mo");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Di");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Mi");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "Do");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(5, "Fr");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(6, "Sa");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(7, "So");

mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.2);
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.WHITE);
mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);


mCurrentRenderer.setFillPoints(false);
mCurrentRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);

mCurrentSeries.add(1, 1);
mCurrentSeries.add(2, 3);
mCurrentSeries.add(3, 0);
mCurrentSeries.add(4, 4);
mCurrentSeries.add(5, 0);
mCurrentSeries.add(6, 0);
mCurrentSeries.add(7, 3);

mChart = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, mDataset, mRenderer,
            Type.STACKED);
```

And this is the result:

[image: my chart]

My Problems:

1. The first bar is IN the X-axis. How can I change this?
2. I tried to change the color for the axis labels, but they are still grey.
3. I do not know the name, but I want to get rid of the small lines/points indicating the exact values above / beside the axes labels.

Answer (score 2):

1. `mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);` If that doesn't work, try making your x-axis min to 0 so it has room to draw and have no label for 0.
2. `mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(yourColor); mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, yourColor);`
3. Not sure about this one. I'll continue looking and update my answer if I find anything.

Comment: Thanks, these hints are very good: while the Align.Right did not work, the x-axis min to 0 did.
Also the colours. In addiditon, I added 
    mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
to my code to prevent the numbers overlaying my own labels in x-axis.
THe only problem left is my issue nr. 3.

Comment: It was a shot in the dark. I tried going through the source for AChartEngine, but it gets messy in parts, and I'm not exactly sure where those are getting drawn.

Comment: It seems that there are settings for nearly everything, even if they are quite hidden. But unfortunately, I found nothing for this issue. I even do not know the names of these "objects", so googling is hard too :(

Comment: I'm not sure they have a name. Do they still show up if you add `mRenderer.showAxes(false)`? A lot of the code involved is just `canvas.drawLine()` and it may or may not be wrapped in it's own conditional `if`.